# swift ios tableview with custom checkmark keeps reselecting cell when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableview with a two sections and a custom checkmark that gets shown when selecting a cell.

The only problem is if I select a cell and scroll down the cell gets re-selected each time the cell shows up on the screen, and all other cells gets hidden again.

So how I can I make that a cell only gets selected/deselected once.

my code:

```
//Keep track of selected row
    var selectedRow: NSIndexPath? = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

    func loadStates() {
        ApiService.getStates() { (JSON) -> () in
            self.states = JSON["stateData"]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadStates()
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let paths:[NSIndexPath]

        if let previous = selectedRow {
            paths = [indexPath, previous]
        } else {
            paths = [indexPath]
        }
        selectedRow = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: .None)

        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
            performSegueWithIdentifier("searchCitySegue", sender: indexPath)
        }else {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (section == 1){
            return states.count
        }
        return 1 
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: searchStateTableViewCell!

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("staticStateCell") as! searchStateTableViewCell
            cell.titleLabel?.text = "All states"

            if indexPath == selectedRow {
               cell.stateImage.select()
            } else {
                cell.stateImage.deselect()
            }

        }else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stateCell") as! searchStateTableViewCell
            let state = states[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureWithStates(state)
            if indexPath == selectedRow {
                cell.stateImage.select()
            } else {
                cell.stateImage.deselect()
            }
        }

        return cell

    }
```

So what is causing my cell to run the selected animation once it reapears on the screen each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with this code:

```
if indexPath == selectedRow {
    cell.stateImage.select()
}
else {
    cell.stateImage.deselect()
}
```

is called each time the cell appears. Try:

```
if indexPath == selectedRow {
    if !(cell.selected) {
        cell.stateImage.select()
    }
}
else {
    cell.stateImage.deselect()
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code but the cell still gets re-selected if I scroll down then up again so it becomes visible on screen : /

Comment: @user2636197 Replace !(cell.selected) with whatever logic in your code determines whether the cell is already in the selected state. That way, if it is, it won't try putting it into the selected state again.

Comment: I have tried it ```if indexPath == selectedRow {
                if !cell.stateImage.selected {
                    cell.stateImage.select()
                    print("select normal")
                }
            } else {
                if cell.stateImage.selected {
                    cell.stateImage.deselect()
                    print("deselect normal")
                }
            }```
Once the cell gets scrolled off screen and back again it gets deselected then selected again. Its really annoying seeing the select animation run each time I scroll back/fourth